# Use streams to merge List<Pair<A,B>> to List<Pair<A,List<B>>> based on key values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm learning java 8 stream now, I'm curious is there any convenient way to convert `List<Pair<A,B>>` to `List<Pair<A,List<B>>>`, which is to merge values of pair by key?

I ever thought to use `forEach` method, but it seems less efficient since I need to traverse the new list to check the key of pair.

Comment: b/c I need to traverse the new list of Pair<A, List<B>> and find the duplicate key A of each pair, then insert corresponding value to the List<B>

Comment: The conceptual data-structure / model would be more clearly described if using `Set` and `Map`, eg: `List<Pair<A,B>>` -> `Map<A,Set<B>>`. Then we know that the output keys (of A) must be unique as well as that values (of B) within each key must be unique (however, neither Map/Set guarantee order by default). This also guides toward the potential usage of HashMap and HashSet as implementations to handle the operation relatively efficiently *iff* the order is not relevant.

Comment: @user2864740 you are right, but after considering there might be values ordered by key A, I don't want to break it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) (which also supports the insertion order of the entries) instead of `List<Pair<>>`. Using that you can simply use `Collectors.groupingBy()` and `Collectors.mapping()` to achieve that:

```
List<Pair<A, B>> list = ...;
Map<A, List<B>> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getKey, LinkedHashMap::new, 
                Collectors.mapping(Pair::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

However if you really need a `List<Pair<>>` you can transform the map back to this:

```
List<Pair<A, B>> list = ...;
List<Pair<A, List<B>>> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getKey, LinkedHashMap::new, 
                Collectors.mapping(Pair::getValue, Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new Pair<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Bare in mind that you iterate **twice** with this solution (first the list, second the map).

Beside that, if you also want to remove duplicates of `B` you can use a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) (which also keeps the order) for that. For this you just need to change the mapping downstream collector:

```
List<Pair<A, B>> list = ...;
Map<A, Set<B>> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getKey, LinkedHashMap::new, 
                Collectors.mapping(Pair::getValue, Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))));
```

Comment: I'm curious if I just use the linkedHashMap, after I call linkedHashMap.steam().collector(Collectors.toMap()), would it keep the order?

Comment: @WilliamZ if you are using `LinkedHashMap::new` as mapFactory supplier yes, if not, no. If you don't provide a mapFactory a `HashMap` (unorderd) is used.